# Restore GAE default storage bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Appengine usually creates a default cloud storage bucket when creating the project. Now I've accidentally deleted the default bucket and I'm unable to re-create this bucket.

Can I somehow manually recreate the default GAE bucket without creating a new cloud project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The default bucket is created once for your project, and if you delete it, it's gone. You could create a new bucket, but it will not receive the default bucket free quota and will be billed like a normal GCS bucket.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a bug.](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11521) As mentioned in the report, it cannot be restored manually, because the user can obviously not verify ownership of the `appspot.com` domain. There has been little activity on the report from Google so it's unlikely to be fixed soon. I raised the issue [on the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/google-appengine/author$3Ame/google-appengine/sBwZd4g49Yw), with no reply.